# Impossible to sort by 2 fields at once with javascript default sort?

Tags: javascript, sorting

I'm trying to sort by 2 fields such that if field 1 isn't available it's sorted by field 2 instead.

Code below field 1 works but field 2 doesn't. Apparently the default sort does not do a thorough comparison of all the elements, only a couple. Should I abandon the default sort and build my own?

Here is the edited jsbin with the current output vs expected: https://jsbin.com/deyebebebu/edit?html,js,output

```
var data = [{
  age: 0,
  title: "a",
}, {
  age: 5,
  title: "b",
}, {
  age: "user did not enter",
  title: "fghetwe",
}, {
  age: "strange data",
  title: "e",
}, {
  age: 5,
  title: "rtyera",
}, {
  age: "user did not enter",
  title: "c",
}, {
  age: "user did not enter",
  title: "e",
}, {
  age: 1,
  title: "c",
}, {
  title: "rtyera",
}, {
  age: 1,
  title: "a",
}, {
  title: "d",
}, {
  age: 2,
  title: "c",
}, {
  age: null,
  title: "d",
}, {
  age: [3],
  title: "c",
}, {
  age: 7,
  title: "c",
}, {
  age: 8,
  title: "a",
}, {
  age: 5,
  title: "h",
}, {
  title: "ayrtyery",
}, {
  title: "a",
}, {
  age: 1,
  title: "a",
}, {
    title: "f",
  }]

var primarySort = "age";
var secondarySort = "title"

var list = Backbone.Collection.extend({
  // Reference to this collection's model.
  comparator: function (a, b) {
    let attr = a.get(primarySort)
    let bAttr = b.get(primarySort)

    if (Array.isArray(attr)) attr = attr.join(" ")
    if (Array.isArray(bAttr)) bAttr = bAttr.join(" ")

    if ((isNaN(parseFloat(attr)) && !isNaN(parseFloat(bAttr)))) {
      return -1
    }
    if (!isNaN(parseFloat(attr)) && isNaN(parseFloat(bAttr))) {
      return 1
    }
    if ((!isNaN(attr) && isNaN(bAttr))) {
      return -1
    }
    if ((isNaN(attr) && !isNaN(bAttr))) {
      return 1
    }


    if (attr != null && bAttr != null && !isNaN(parseFloat(attr)) && !isNaN(parseFloat(bAttr))) {
      attr = parseFloat(attr)
      bAttr = parseFloat(bAttr)
      if (attr > bAttr) return 1
      if (attr < bAttr) return -1
      if (attr == bAttr) {
        if (a.get(secondarySort) > b.get(secondarySort)) {
          return 1
        }
        else if (a.get(secondarySort) < b.get(secondarySort)) {
          return -1
        }
      }
    }

    if ((!attr && attr != 0) && (bAttr || bAttr == 0)) {
      return -1
    }

    if ((!bAttr && bAttr != 0) && (attr || attr == 0)) {
      return 1
    }

    if (!attr && attr != 0 && !bAttr && bAttr != 0) {
      if (a.get(secondarySort) > b.get(secondarySort)) {
        return 1
      }
      else if (a.get(secondarySort) < b.get(secondarySort)) {
        return -1
      }

      return 0
    }


    if (isNaN(attr) || isNaN(bAttr)) {
      if (attr > bAttr) return 1
      if (attr < bAttr) return -1
      return 0
    }

    if (a.get(secondarySort) > b.get(secondarySort)) {
      return 1
    }
    else if (a.get(secondarySort) < b.get(secondarySort)) {
      return -1
    }
    else {
      return 0
    }
  },
})


console.log(new list(data).toJSON())
document.getElementById("first").innerHTML += JSON.stringify(new list(data).toJSON(), undefined, 2)

// expected
var firstexpected = [
  {
    "title": "a"
  },
  {
    "title": "ayrtyery"
  },
  {
    "age": null,
    "title": "d"
  },
  {
    "title": "d"
  },
  {
    "title": "f"
  },
  {
    "title": "rtyera"
  },
  {
    "age": "user did not enter",
    "title": "c"
  },
  {
    "age": "strange data",
    "title": "e"
  },
  {
    "age": "user did not enter",
    "title": "e"
  },
  {
    "age": "user did not enter",
    "title": "fghetwe"
  },
  {
    "age": 0,
    "title": "a"
  },
  {
    "age": 1,
    "title": "a"
  },
  {
    "age": 1,
    "title": "a"
  },
  {
    "age": 1,
    "title": "c"
  },
  {
    "age": 2,
    "title": "c"
  },
  {
    "age": [
      3
    ],
    "title": "c"
  },
  {
    "age": 5,
    "title": "b"
  },
  {
    "age": 5,
    "title": "h"
  },
  {
    "age": 5,
    "title": "rtyera"
  },
  {
    "age": 7,
    "title": "c"
  },
  {
    "age": 8,
    "title": "a"
  }
]





primarySort = "title";
secondarySort = "age"

document.getElementById("second").innerHTML += JSON.stringify(new list(data).toJSON(), undefined, 2)

var secondexpected = [
  {
    "title": "a"
  },
  {
    "age": 0,
    "title": "a"
  },
  {
    "age": 1,
    "title": "a"
  },
  {
    "age": 1,
    "title": "a"
  },
  {
    "age": 8,
    "title": "a"
  },
  {
    "title": "ayrtyery"
  },
  {
    "age": 5,
    "title": "b"
  },
  {
    "age": "user did not enter",
    "title": "c"
  },
  {
    "age": 1,
    "title": "c"
  },
  {
    "age": 2,
    "title": "c"
  },
  {
    "age": [
      3
    ],
    "title": "c"
  },
  {
    "age": 7,
    "title": "c"
  },
  {
    "title": "d"
  },
  {
    "age": null,
    "title": "d"
  },
  {
    "age": "strange data",
    "title": "e"
  },
  {
    "age": "user did not enter",
    "title": "e"
  },
  {
    "title": "f"
  },
  {
    "age": "user did not enter",
    "title": "fghetwe"
  },
  {
    "age": 5,
    "title": "h"
  },
  {
    "title": "rtyera"
  },
  {
    "age": 5,
    "title": "rtyera"
  },
]
```

This isn't right:

```
  {
    "age": "user did not enter",
    "title": "fghetwe"
  },
  {
    "age": "user did not enter",
    "title": "c"
  },
  {
    "age": "user did not enter",
    "title": "e"
  },
```

I'm going to delete the older code examples since we have a more clear jsbin.

Comment: Please add a sample of the input array and the expected output for two fields with optional data.

Comment: @adiga so it's not impossible? I just want to know if it's impossible or not not a full solution.

Comment: It's unclear what you're asking without seeing a sample of the input, the fields to be sorted by and the expected output.

Comment: What is the expected output after sorting for `data` in jsbin?

Comment: @adiga ok built a new example with more expected outputs included in the bin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a function which compares 2 objects `a, b` based on the `field` property provided.

```js
const data = [{ age: 0, title: "a", }, { age: 5, title: "b", }, { age: "user did not enter", title: "fghetwe", }, { age: "strange data", title: "e", }, { age: 5, title: "rtyera", }, { age: "user did not enter", title: "c", }, { age: "user did not enter", title: "e", }, { age: 1, title: "c", }, { title: "rtyera", }, { age: 1, title: "a", }, { title: "d", }, { age: 2, title: "c", }, { age: null, title: "d", }, { age: [3], title: "c", }, { age: 7, title: "c", }, { age: 8, title: "a", }, { age: 5, title: "h", }, { title: "ayrtyery", }, { title: "a", }, { age: 1, title: "a", }, { title: "f", }];

// checks if a value is null OR undefined
const isNullish = v => v === null || typeof v === 'undefined'
const isNullOrNaN = v => v === null || isNaN(v)

// to comapre 2 based on the field type 
function compare(a, b, field) {
  const aValue = a[field], bValue = b[field];

  return isNullish(bValue) - isNullish(aValue) 
           || isNullOrNaN(bValue) - isNullOrNaN(aValue) 
           || (aValue > bValue ? 1 : aValue < bValue ? -1 : 0)
}

const customSort = (input, primarySort, secondarySort) =>
  input.sort((a, b) =>
    compare(a, b, primarySort) || compare(a, b, secondarySort)
  )

console.log(customSort(data, 'age', 'title'))
console.log(customSort(data, 'title', 'age'))
```

Inside the `compare` function, get the type of the current property being compared.

1) The objects which have `undefined` and `null` are given the highest priority. The `isNullish` function returns true or false based on the value. Subtract the booleans returned for `aValue` and `bValue`. This will return 1, -1 or 0.

```
const isNullish = v => v === null || typeof v === 'undefined'
```

2) If both of them are equal, the resulting value will be `0`, which is [falsy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy). So, the next condition in `||` will be checked. Similarly, check the values for `NaN`. Subtract the resulting booleans of `isNaN`

3) If the values still return zero, compare them to return 1, -1 or 0

```
// to comapre 2 based on the field type 
function compare(a, b, field) {
  const aValue = a[field], bValue = b[field];

  return isNullish(bValue) - isNullish(aValue) 
           || isNaN(bValue) - isNaN(aValue) 
           || (aValue > bValue ? 1 : aValue < bValue ? -1 : 0)
}
```

Then use this compare function in sort. First, sort the items based on `primarySort` field. If that method returns `0`, the `secondarySort` function will be called in `||` and `a, b` will be sorted based on that

```
const customSort = (input, primarySort, secondarySort) =>
  input.sort((a, b) =>
    compare(a, b, primarySort) || compare(a, b, secondarySort)
  )
```

You might have to tweak `aValue = a[field]` to `a.get(field)` for backbone

Comment: Thank you for the great answer. Unfortunately both the fields and the values are not in my control, I don't know what the user will be sorting by and what type they are. I need to check first, with isNaN though I suppose I can do the checking before the sort? It's possible for it to be a multitude of types though for sanity's sake I'm limiting it to numbers and strings.

Comment: @Harry instead of type you could also directly check for the `field` itself inside `compare`. `if(field === 'age' || field === 'otherNumberField') { // number logic } else { // string logic}`

Comment: The thing is age is just an example and it could be literally anything. For example it could be 'yearssubscribed' and I wouldn't know that in advance. Checking during comparison doesn't seem quite to work for me. aValue could be undefined or a string but could actually be a number. This isn't working: https://jsbin.com/fewumayefi/edit?html,js,console
`(isNaN(parseFloat(attr)) && !isNaN(parseFloat(bAttr)))
    (!isNaN(attr) && isNaN(bAttr))` That's why I have this whole situation.

Comment: @Harry I have updated. Now it uses `>` and ternary operators to compare the values. This works for strings and number. This should *probably* work.

Comment: Thanks again, I edited the example to break the sort: https://jsbin.com/cacamiceze/edit?html,js,console Can you take a look at this?

Comment: @Harry aargh, `isNaN(null)` is `false` but `isNaN` undefined is `true`. You can create another custom check like `const isNullOrNaN = v => v === null || isNaN(v)` So that they are treated with same preference

Comment: Thanks, what's the best way to handle empty string value? Right now I have something like this: `const aValue = a[field] === "" ? null : a[field], bValue = b[field] === "" ? null : b[field];`

Comment: @Harry does adding `|| v === ''` in `isNullish` work?

Comment: @Harry it's the same reason as null. `isNaN('')` returns false. So, you could `const isNullish = v => v === '' || v === null || typeof v === 'undefined'` and 
`const isNullOrNaN = v => isNullish(v) || isNaN(v)`

Comment: Thanks again for all your help